# jersey ContainerRequestFilter : getPathParameters gives empty values

Tags: filter, jersey, maps, jax-rs, path-parameter

I have an authorization filter. While trying to retrieve pathparameters, I am unable to get the values.
could someone please tell me, what is wrong with the below code.

```
@AuthorizedAccess  //named exception
@Provider
public class AuthorizedAccessFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

/** The Constant logger. */
private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthorizedAccessFilter.class);


public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

        logger.info(AUTH_MESSAGE, requestContext.getUriInfo().getAbsolutePath());
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParameters = requestContext.getUriInfo().getPathParameters();
        for (Entry<String, List<String>> e : pathParameters.entrySet()) {
            logger.info( " key :value " +e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
        logger.info("pathparammap = {} ",pathParameters.size());

 }
```

> and it returns:
>      it returns key name but it doesn't return the value.

```
AuthorizedAccessFilter  -  key value entity-id
AuthorizedAccessFilter  - pathparammap = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like a simple incorrect format (1-st argument) in logger. You need to specify at least one `{}` that would be replaced with value of 2-nd `logger.info` argument

```
logger.info( " key :value {}" + e.getKey(), e.getValue());
or 
logger.info( " key :value {} {}" , e.getKey() , e.getValue());
```

Also take a look at [SLF4J documentation](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance)